# Inject JMS ConnectionFactory and Queue into a WebSocket?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, websocket, jms, wildfly

I have a simple WebSocket implemented in JavaEE 7 that I would like to act as a JMS producer.  However, when I try and inject the `ConnectionFactory` and `Queue` into it as a JavaEE `@Resource` I always see that it is null.  My code looks like this:

```
@Named
@ServerEndpoint("/hello")
public class WebSocketA implements Serializable {

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/JmsXA")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test")
    private Queue testQueue = null;

  ...

}
```

Is there a reason why I cannot inject these `Resource`s?  Is this not supported within JavaEE WebSockets?  I am deploying on Wildfly 8.1, and my application is a simple WAR with only the WebSocket implementation class within it.

Comment: There are known issues with CDI and WebSockets (https://java.net/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/GLASSFISH-20468) but AFAIK they don't affect `@Resource` injection. Have you tried a different server, perhaps Glassfish 4 to make sure it's not a Wildfly issue?

Comment: I have not.  Our deployment environment is JBoss/Wildfly, so we need to make sure we can get it working on that platform.  It doesn't help us if it works on Glassfish, unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure that the configured JNDI-name is correct?  You can manually lookup the JNDI name to test, see, e.g., https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/master/helloworld-jms/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/jms/HelloWorldJMSClient.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there are some issues with JMS injection using certain CDI beans. I was able to get the injection to work by using `@javax.inject.Singleton` or `@javax.ejb.Stateless`. I removed the `@Named` annotation in both cases. I did not test the injection of the `Queue`, just the `ConnectionFactory`

I tested with the latest Glassfish 4 promoted build with a simple web project with just the WebSocket class:

```
@Stateless
@ServerEndpoint("/hello")
public class WsTest implements Serializable {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(WsTest.class.getName());

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:comp/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "onOpen {0}", connectionFactory);
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("onOpen");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String echo(String message) {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "onMessage({0}) {1}", new Object[]{message, connectionFactory});
        return message + " (from your server)";
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "onError {0}", connectionFactory);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "onClose {0}", connectionFactory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll be sure to give this a try in Wildfly/JBoss to see if it works for me.